# How to resize the graphic shapes in Pixijs (using vertex pointers) similar to what we do in paint or word applications?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I am able to draw and resize the graphics shapes statically using pixijs.

I want to resize the shapes dynamically using the vertex pointers similar to the following image -
[image: Reference Image]

Can anyone please guide me on how can this be achieved?